# Oracle SQL: Create a new row for each value in a column with more values separated by comma

Tags: sql, string, oracle, csv, unnest

I have the following table

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1

 Date            ID          Completed_Task
01/01/2019       X300         SA, MA, TY
01/01/2019       X400         SA, GT, JY
01/01/2019       X500         SA, GT, TY
```

I need the table to have one Completed_Task per row and count of that completed_task(it will be 1 if it happened once)

Desired Output:

```
 Date            ID          Completed_Task     Count
01/01/2019       X300             SA             1
01/01/2019       X300             MA             1
01/01/2019       X300             TY             1
01/01/2019       X400             SA             1   
01/01/2019       X400             GT             1  
01/01/2019       X400             JY             1        
01/01/2019       X500             SA             1
01/01/2019       X500             GT             1
01/01/2019       X500             TY             1
```

Let me know how I can achieve this in Oracle Sql. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a JSON approach?

```
select t.dt, t.id, x.task
from table1 t
cross apply json_table(
    '["' || replace(completed_task, ', ', '", "') || '"]',
    '$[*]' columns (task varchar2(10) path '$')
) x
```

The idea is to treat the CSV list as a JSON array. For this, we user string functions, to turn something like `'SA, MA, TY'` to `["SA", "MA", "TY"]`. Then, we can use set-returning function `json_table()` to unnest the array to rows.

Comment: This works .. It splits the values with comma and insert a row. But the count part is tricky to add in this right ?

Comment: @Virat: which logic do you want for the count? All rows in your result show `1`, so I can't guess.

Comment: Yeah. I created a column with 1. So, this logic is perfect !!